# Multiple packages installation using bash

Tags: command-line, apt, bash

As we all know, the command we use in order to install multiple packages is:

```
apt install package1 package2 package3`
```

Using the following method in a Bash script:

```
packages="package1 package2 package3"
apt install "$packages"
```

produces an error saying that the package cannot be located. Therefore it's incorrect.

Does the following command run `apt` once for each package or does it work differently?

```
apt install $(cat $packageFile)
```

assuming that *packageFile* is a text file containing the package names one per line.

I know that I can use an array and place all package names in it and then use a *for* loop to run `apt` once for each package, but I'm wondering if there's a way to install all of them,  using a Bash script, running `apt` only once.

Thank you.

Comment: Related: [Shell-Check failure](https://askubuntu.com/q/1460416)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The approach of using an array is correct, but you need to define properly the array. This means that you need to use a compound statement (i.e. round brackets) instead of double quotes.
In fact, the reason why your command does not work in the first place is because `$packages` gets expanded by the shell to `package1 package2 package3` which is then read as a single string by `apt`, not separately as `package1`, `package2`, `package3`.

Therefore, define an array using a compound assignment in the following form:

```
packages=(package1 package2 package3)
```

and then install all the packages using the following command:

```
sudo apt install "${packages[@]}"
```

In fact, any element of an array may be referenced using `${array_name[index]}`, and when the index is `@`, the word expands to all members of the array name. The use of braces is required to avoid conflicts with the shell’s filename expansion operators.

Comment: Oh. This is a very nice solution. I hadn't realized that an array could be accessed this way. Thank you very much.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. I did some fixes to the answer adding some details. If you find it useful, please accept it.

Comment: @LorenzKeel The reason that the OP's command does not work in the first place is because `$packages` gets expanded by the shell to `package1 package2 package3` which is then read as a single string by `apt`, not separately as `package1`, `package2`, `package3`. You might want to add this into your answer to make it more complete. ;)